# Downgrade Safari Browser

Tags: macos, safari

I have a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8.5 and I have downloaded the wrong Safari browser, for OS X 10.10.

It says "You can't use this version of the application "Safari" with this version of OS X".

How to downgrade the incorrect version for OS X 10.10 and replace with the newest Safari for OS X 10.8.5?

Answer (score 1):

From: [Get the latest version of Safari for your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204416)

> You can keep Safari up to date by keeping macOS up to date.
>
> [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/) is included with your Mac. To get the latest version of Safari, [install the latest macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201475).
>
> To keep Safari up to date for an earlier macOS, [install the latest
>   updates](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201541) for that macOS.

**Note:** Updated to reflect changes in Apple Support HT204416 as of: Jun 15, 2017